# List of zsh bindkey commands

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

Where can I find a list of `zsh` commands that I can use with `bindkey`, with descriptions?

Each time that I look for name of some standard action (e.g., `end-of-line`), I need to google and guess that the command found is what I look for.

**Related**:

- [Interpret zsh bindkey escaped sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314161/interpret-zsh-bindkey-escaped-sequences) (SO)
- [The Z-Shell Line Editor](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html) (doc)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Commands available for use in the line editor are referred to as widgets. The standard widgets are listed in the `zshzle` manpage in the `STANDARD WIDGETS` section. That manpage is also [available from the zsh website](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets)

Comment: I don't see any options in the "movement' section at that link that correspond to "page up" or "page down" behavior. Does zsh bindkey simply not offer that as a built-in option?

Comment: @ely That seems more like a new question than a comment on this question+answer. What are you expecting for page up/down? If you're looking for something to scroll the displayed content, that would be a binding in your terminal, not something in zsh (or other shell).

Comment: This answer seems far more useful than the others above it. Also, those other ones don't include documentation, so technically, they're not answering the question. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 93):

- `bindkey -l` will give you a list of existing keymap names.
- `bindkey -M <keymap>` will list all the bindings in a given keymap.
- If you use the zsh command line in emacs mode, then the `emacs` keymap is likely to be most important for you.
- If you use it in vi mode, then you’d be interested in `viins` and `vicmd`.

(See the `zshzle(1)` man page for more details.)

Once you have a list of keybindings, you can search the official [ZLE documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Widgets) for the name of the action (or “widget” in zsh parlance).

*Edit:* Elsewhere in this thread, Dave Lee answers the original question more accurately than I do here!

Comment: Also, executing `bindkey` with no arguments will print all keybindings.

Comment: @KeithHughitt That is true, but only for the current keymap. Which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Ah, good catch - I thought it was printing everything. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Actually my earlier comment wasn’t quite accurate either! Using `bindkey` without arguments will show the contents of the `main` keymap. `main` is an alias for either `emacs` or `viins`, depending on whether you’ve set up emacs- or vi-like line editing. The contents of `vicmd` can only be seen by using the `-M` flag.

Answer (score 54):

```
zle -al
```

lists all registered zle commands

Comment: Thanks, this was what I am looking for.

Comment: This is a more exact answer of the original question than my answer above. Have an upvote!

One could also mention that the list of standard widgets is available in the Zsh manual at:

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-widgets_002c-standard

Answer (score 15):

1. Zsh Line Editor Doc: https://web.cs.elte.hu/local/texinfo/zsh/zsh_10.html
2. Look up system current bindkey setting: `$ bindkey`, eg(`$ bindkey|grep case`, looking for down-case);
3. `$ zle -al` used for list all registered zle commands;
4. Bind your personal key for zsh command ,  `$ vim ~/.zshrc`, add

```
# bindkey
bindkey "^U"    backward-kill-line
bindkey "^u"    backward-kill-line
bindkey "^[l"   down-case-word
bindkey "^[L"   down-case-word

# alt+<- | alt+->
bindkey "^[f" forward-word
bindkey "^[b" backward-word

# ctrl+<- | ctrl+->
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word
```

5. See other things: oh-my-zsh down-case-word bug:  https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/commit/55a9d685fd960390a4f400ac461d901049a78beb

Comment: The official documentation for Zsh Line Editor is http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html; the link you refer to is only a copy maintained by some university in Hungary.

Comment: @lupguo how does one bind super/win key though?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on zsh via putty. For me the bindings were different. You can find this out with `CTRL+V` followed by for example the left arrow. It will display the used character sequence. So for me it was:

```
bindkey "^[[D" backward-word
bindkey "^[[C" forward-word
bindkey "^H" backward-kill-word
```

Comment: The `read` command worked for me since I bound `ctrl+v` to paste: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/find-and-bind-key-sequences-in-bash/

Answer (score 1):

After installing `oh-my-zsh`, I typed `bindkey 'anything'` then press tab, then say `yes`. The list of available bindkeys will be flushed out